# Is there a way to have managed processes in Perl (i.e. a threads replacement that actually works)?

Tags: perl, multithreading, fork, signals

I have a multithreded application in perl for which I have to rely on several non-thread safe modules, so I have been using `fork()`ed processes with `kill()` signals as a message passing interface.

The problem is that the signal handlers are a bit erratic (to say the least) and often end up with processes that get killed in inapropriate states.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [forks.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rybskej/forks-0.27/lib/forks.pm), a "drop-in replacement for Perl threads using fork()" which makes for much more sensible memory usage (but don't use it on Win32).  It will allow you to declare "shared" variables and then it automatically passes changes made to such variables between the processes (similar to how threads.pm does things).

Answer (score 7):

Depending on exactly what your program needs to do, you might consider using [POE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE), which is a Perl framework for multi-threaded applications with user-space threads.  It's complex, but elegant and powerful and can help you avoid non-thread-safe modules by confining activity to a single Perl interpreter thread.

Helpful resources to get started:

- [Programming POE](http://axkit.org/docs/presentations/tpc2002/poe.pdf) presentation by Matt Sergeant (start here to understand what it is and does)
- [POE project page](http://poe.perl.org) (lots of cookbook examples)

Plus there are hundreds of pre-built [POE components](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=POE::Component&mode=module) you can use to assemble into an application.

Answer (score 6):

You can always have a pipe between parent and child to pass messages back and forth.

```
pipe my $reader, my $writer;
my $pid = fork();
if ( $pid == 0 ) {
    close $reader;
    ...
}
else {
    close $writer;
    my $msg_from_child = <$reader>;
    ....
}
```

Not a very comfortable way of programming, but it shouldn't be 'erratic'.

Answer (score 1):

From perl 5.8 onwards you should be looking at the core threads module. Have a look at http://metacpan.org/pod/threads

If you want to use modules which aren't thread safe you can usually load them with a require and import inside the thread entry point.